# Como referenciar a Library Knockout.js instalada via NPM

Tags: javascript, knockoutjs

Instalei a library do Knockout.js via NPM, pelo seguinte comando:

```
npm install --save-dev knockout
```

Reparei que o NPM instala o módulo dentro da pasta node_modules/knockout, mas acredito que exista uma forma de incluir o script no projeto sem ter que referenciá-lo pelo seguinte caminho no meu index.html:

```
<script src="node_modules/knockout/build/output/knockout-lastest.js></script>
```

Como faço para incluir da forma correta?

Comment: Onde estás a usar o `Knockout`?  tens algum compilador como webpack, browserify?

Comment: não @Sergio. Só instalei via NPM. devo instalar o webpack e chamar o pacote por lá?

Comment: Nesse caso parece-me mais simles usar um CDN "à moda antiga". Se quiseres esconder possiveis variáveis globais do Knockout.js podes usar um desses compiladores/empacotadores ou o require.js. Mas vais estar a juntar complexidade que pode só atrapalhar...

Comment: Entendi..Queria usar via NPM só para experimentar mesmo. Mas concordo com você que talvez não compense deixar complexo algo que pode ser mais simples. Obrigada pela sua ajuda, @Sergio

Comment: De nada. Pois, é sempre bom experimentar. E podes sim usar localmente, indo buscar a `node_modules`. Onde está o teu ficheiro HTML em comparação com o `node_modules`? Tens servidor ou estás a testar localmente?

Comment: estou usando localmente.O index está dentro da pasta "source". Voltando um nível, vem a pasta node_modules na raiz do projeto. Meu objetivo é criar uma pasta com arquivos de edição do projeto, e outra pasta de publicação, chamada "dist", onde incluirei, após executar o grunt, todos os arquivos da pasta source minificados e concatenados.

Comment: Para usar o Knockout.js via `node_modules` podes fazer `<script src="../node_modules/knockout/build/output/knockout-lastest.js></script>` se é que compreendi bem a estrutura das diretorias. Podias pôr o Grunt a ir buscar esse ficheiro ao `node_modules` e usar a partir de `dist` também... várias opções :)

Comment: Beleza @Sergio! Muito obrigada ;)